# What type of training was Class E's Yuuma going to say, before he corrected himself?

Tags: assassination-classroom

Assassination Classroom - Chapter 24, page 18, second panel

What was the character about to say?

[image: Assassination Classroom]

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say Anbu from Naruto lol. Maybe the cutoff word is ambush?

Comment: @krikara "Ambush" looks right.

Comment: @krikara I like Anbu, but I also think "ambush training" is correct. Please add that as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: The original reads: "待ち伏せ…いや木登りの特訓してるので", so yeah, ambush.

Comment: I knew senshin would come in here deciphering the Kanji. You should put it as an answer ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Japanese, the panel reads:

> ありがとねぇ　ジャマな枝　切ってくれて
>
> それにしても　君達えらく　身軽だね～
>
> いえいえ
>
> **待ち伏せ**…いや　木登り特訓　してるので

The translation in the OP post is a little bit off; a better translation of the last speech bubble is "It's because we were preparing an ambu-... er, practicing climbing trees." That is, they weren't doing "ambush training"; they were just lying in wait to ambush someone. (In other words, it's not 待ち伏せの特訓 that was elided - just 待ち伏せ.)

Anyway, the word in question is **ambush**.